# How can I download my own video I uploaded to Facebook to my hard drive?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I have the link of the video in my storyteller. But whenever site I paste the link I'm getting error say "the video might be private and not public".

But I never set it to private. Any way to download my own video/s ?